# Map from URL not loading despite working with URL of same format from the examples (ArcGIS macOS SDK)

Tags: swift, arcgis

I'm trying to load OpenStreetMap into a program I'm writing in Swift, using the ArcGIS SDK for macOS. I have the loading of built in maps (`theMap.map = AGSMap(basemap: AGSBasemap.imagery())`) working but I cannot seem to load OpenStreetMap from its URL.

This is the URL I am using: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b834a68d7a484c5fb473d4ba90d35e71

I am using the following code to load the URL, taken from the ArcGIS Examples:

```
let openStreetMap = "https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b834a68d7a484c5fb473d4ba90d35e71"

let tiles = AGSArcGISVectorTiledLayer(url: URL(string: openStreetMap)!)
theMap.map = AGSMap(basemap: AGSBasemap(baseLayer: tiles))
```

The map does not load and all I end up with is a grey gridded background. Surprisingly, if I swap the URL with one I found in the ArcGIS examples (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4e1133c28ac04cca97693cf336cd49ad), that map loads with no problems. The two URLs are in exactly the same format but only one works. Why is this and how can I get it to load the OpenStreetMap URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you require the use of the ARCGIS SDK, this is an alternative method using mapkit.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let osm = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")

    self.map.add(osm)

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if let tile = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {

        let renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tile)

        return renderer
    }

    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to its description, the first URL is a tiled mapservice, while the second one is a Vector.
Maybe you should declare the layer as AGSArcGISTiledLayer